Updating Token Icon
How can I update our token icon on phantom? We recently updated it. Since it was launched on pumpkin I understand it may be immutable but I’ve seen it done with other projects including Retardio.

This question is similar to: How to make token logo appear consistently in Phantom?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
